# parsing json child nodes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having trouble trying to parse JSON with child nodes using jquery. I keep getting no values from the json. My code to parse json is as follows:

```
 function getSC () {
  var sc2url = 'http://sc2ranks.com/api/base/teams/sea/Classified$788.json?appKey=foo.bar?jsonp=sc2test?';
 $.ajax({
  url: sc2url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsonp=sc2test',
  success: sc2test,
  cache: true
 })
}

function sc2test(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var test = data['teams'][0]['divison'];
  console.log(test);
}
```

and the json that is returned is:

```
 {
    "portrait": {
        "row": 0,
        "icon_id": 0,
        "column": 0
    },
    "character_code": 788,
    "updated_at": "2012-05-08T01:33:27Z",
    "achievement_points": 970,
    "teams": [
        {
            "fav_race": "protoss",
            "bracket": 1,
            "division": "Division Zekrath Dixie",
            "ratio": "1.00",
            "world_rank": 8683,
            "wins": 97,
            "is_random": false,
            "updated_at": "2012-05-09T08:25:54Z",
            "losses": 0,
            "points": 342,
            "region_rank": 303,
            "division_rank": 21,
            "league": "diamond"
        }
    ],
    "bnet_id": 39578,
    "name": "Classified",
    "region": "sea",
    "id": 1645881
}
```

there is 2 child nodes in it and I would like to know how I can parse them using jQuery of javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `data` contain the right value? Your `$.ajax` settings seem a bit strange.... if you set it up properly, `data` will already contain the parsed data. For learning how to process objects, please read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)... this is basic JavaScript knowledge.

Comment: Tried something like `data.teams[0].division`?

Comment: Stupid question, but did you type `division` or `divison`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelled `division`. You have `divison`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5uCEf/)

Comment: i cannot believe that just happened. thanks.